# Sharepoint web-form submit Thanks Message issue

Tags: form

I have a web-part that includes a simple web-form. After submitting the web-form the user will receive an apropiate succes/error  message.

In the codeBehind for the Click_event of the submit button I have:

```
lblMessage.Text = "Your Profile Details were updated successfully";
```

And code in the asxc file:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

The problem is that message don't disappear after page refresh F5.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that F5 isn't reload page, but replay last request. So pressing F5 will post the previous content once more.

Instead of showing a readonly form with a message will cause a lot of users to press F5 in order to get a new form ready for input the two following solutions will be better:

- Redirect to a new page with confirmation
- Show form ready for new input and include javascript to show a notification that previous input was accepted